# how to maintain table log (every changes) history in MS SQL by write trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

We just want to maintain table log (every changes) history in MS SQL by write trigger please suggest

i tried but not working

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_ServiceDescriptionTable]
ON ServiceDescriptionMaster
After UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
        declare @Rate money;
        Select @Rate = Rate from inserted;

        update [dbo].[ServiceDescriptionMasterlog] set Rate = @Rate 
        where Service_Description = '';
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya good.
If you want to maintain evry changes log then you can insert in same log table with all field like as follows:

**1)** create same table like "ServiceDescriptionMasterlog" with one Extra Field (Column) Entry_DateTime set default bind getdate() method.

**2)** write a trigger on "ServiceDescriptionMaster" table as follows:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ServiceDescriptionMaster_OnUpdate]
ON [dbo].[ServiceDescriptionMaster]
After UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON; 
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceDescriptionMasterLog]
       (S_No,Rate,.....)
       select S_No,Rate,.....
       from Deleted;
END
```

you can also maintain on delete:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ServiceDescriptionMaster_OnDelete]
ON [dbo].[ServiceDescriptionMaster]
For Delete
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON; 
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceDescriptionMasterLog]
       (S_No,Rate,.....)
       select S_No,Rate,.....
       from Deleted;
END
```

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh Sharma

Comment: Thank you so much @shamim sir :) (Y)